# SQL Server : varchar convert to datetime error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But I still get this result

[image]

And I also want to ask if why is the time still showing when I use the 102 date format.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mPDF_gen048] 



@gfromDate varchar(10), -- '3/16/2016'
@gtoDate varchar(10) -- '3/18/2016'


AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @fromDate date
declare @toDate date
declare @totaldays int

set @fromDate  = (select convert (varchar(10), @gfromDate, 101))
set @toDate  = (select convert (varchar(10), @gtoDate, 101))

select @fromDate

set @totaldays = (select datediff(day,@fromdate,@toDate)+2)

declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
declare @tablename varchar(20)
declare @counter int = 1


while @counter < @totaldays
begin
    set @tablename = (select upper(convert(varchar(8), @fromDate, 106)))
    set @tablename = replace(@tablename,' ','')


    set @sql = @sql + 'SELECT uploadtime, updatedby, updatetime, FROM gen_048_' +  @tablename + ' WHERE refdate = ' + @fromDate

    if(@counter < @totaldays-1)

    set @fromDate = dateadd(day,1,@fromDate)
    set @counter = @counter + 1



end

--print @sql
exec (@sql)

end
```

Comment: your `@fromDate` and `@toDate` is datetime data type. Datetime data type always contain both date & time component

Comment: how can I remove the time on that datetime format?  I thought converting it to varchar and setting it to 10 characters will limit its data to display

Comment: @VinceOsana: if you don't need the time, use the `DATE` datatype (instead of `DATETIME`) available in SQL Server **2008** and newer.

Comment: use `date` data type or format the result in your application

Comment: I already change the 'datetime' to 'date' only but it still shows the time on result

Comment: I copied the whole code here I still cant find what is wrong here I've been working on this error since yesterday

Comment: Vince Osana: Please try with my code and get back to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mPDF_gen048] @gfromDate VARCHAR(10) = '3/16/2016'
    ,@gtoDate VARCHAR(10) = '3/18/2016'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @fromDate DATE
    DECLARE @toDate DATE
    DECLARE @totaldays INT

    SET @fromDate = (
            SELECT convert(VARCHAR(10), @gfromDate, 101)
            )
    SET @toDate = (
            SELECT convert(VARCHAR(10), @gtoDate, 101)
            )

    SELECT @fromDate

    SET @totaldays = (
            SELECT datediff(day, @fromdate, @toDate) + 2
            )

    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) = ''
    DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @counter INT = 1

    WHILE @counter < @totaldays
    BEGIN
        SET @tablename = (
                SELECT upper(convert(VARCHAR(8), @fromDate, 106))
                )
        SET @tablename = replace(@tablename, ' ', '')
        SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT uploadtime, updatedby, updatetime FROM gen_048_' + @tablename + ' WHERE refdate = ''' + convert(VARCHAR(10), @fromDate) + ''''

        IF (@counter < @totaldays - 1)
            SET @fromDate = dateadd(day, 1, @fromDate)
        SET @counter = @counter + 1
    END

    --PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql)
END
```

Comment: Still doesn't show the result from the table, I changed the `SELECT upper(convert(VARCHAR(8), @fromDate, 106))` into this `(SELECT REPLACE(UPPER(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @fromDate, 106), 8)), ' ', '') AS [Mon-YYYY])` to select my table. My table name is gen_048_MAR2016

Comment: last one question sir, how can I remove the - from the YYYY-MM-DD to become YYYYMMDD. i'm trying this one (convert(VARCHAR(10), @fromDate), '-', '')

Comment: why should you remove '-'

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I just got home from school. I thought that I need to remove that "-" between the dates to match the `refdate` from my table to fetch the data. but its all working fine now, thanks to your help.